# Prevent select on input text field using Class and Tag Name

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to prevent selection on an input field with the following:

**considerations**

1. Prevent selection using mouse
2. Prevent selection using keyboard (including Ctrl+A, shift+arrows)
3. Allow focusing into field using keyboard and mouse

So far I have tried these things:
The id is work well but i want to tag name.

**HTML**

```
<p class="noselect">
 Unselectable text.
 <input class="my_input" type="text" value="Try to select me!">
</p>
```

**JS**

```
var inp = document.getElementByClassName('my_input');
inp.addEventListener('select', function() {
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are minor corrections in given code snippet.

1. **getElementsByClassName** instead of **getElementByClassName**
2. **getElementsByClassName** returns array of dom elements with given class so selecting 1st one using **inp[0]**.

```js
var inp = document.getElementsByClassName('my_input');
inp[0].addEventListener('select', function() {
  this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd;
}, false);
```